How to install an RPM file on CentOS into a custom location
On a CentOS 7.8 machine I install locally present RPM files usually with
sudo yum localinstall /path/to/file.rpm

Now I want to install a large RPM which yum lists as 1.1GB when it would install it.
On that particular machine the normal install path (/usr/...) is on a file system which has by far not enough room for this. But we have other file systems mounted with a lot more space (for example /extra/opt).
How can I tell yum (or if yum can't do it rpm) to install into a custom location, say, under the directory /extra/opt?
